# Kotlin, race condition issue

Tags: synchronization, kotlin

Relevant code [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09)

Essentially, we have two thread, one leading the rendering that keeps calling [`display()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L101) and another one, that takes care about user inputs, calling the corresponding [mouse or key event](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L192-L228) accordingly

[Viewpole](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L301) and [object](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L69) poles are nothing else that helper classes to facilitate the matrix handling regarding the camera and the object(s).

Their methods are called both from the `display()` and the user input methods.

`display()` calls both [`viewpole.calcMatrix()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L109) and [`objectpole.calcMatrix()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L150) while the input thread calls them indirectly, for example [`basicLighting.mouseDragged()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L215) -> [`objectpole.mouseDragged()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L178) -> [`rotateView()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L191) -> [`calcMatrix()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L237)

The race condition started to pop up when I began to use [pool objects](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L575-L602) to reduce the GC pressure in specific scenarios. I checked tens of time, each object is being used only once (except with `when`).

I detect race condition by printing out the [view matrix](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L119) each `display()` call. Whenever it's different, it means I got one. An example [here](https://gist.github.com/elect86/4d37b425b4a02a6a7e2c499c7546226e).

Investigating, I found out using simple `println`, for example, that the [`Viewpole.calcMatrix()`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/mousePole.kt#L345) sometimes was getting called before another call has finished to execute it completely.

Adding `@Synchronized` on each `calcMatrix()` (viewpole and objectpole) reduced it a lot, I'd say 80/90%.

But still, some times, I experience race condition. I tried to `synchronize(lock){}` also every call from the user input thread, like [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut09/basicLighting.kt#L205):

```
val lock = Any()

override fun mousePressed(e: MouseEvent) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        viewPole.mousePressed(e)
        objectPole.mousePressed(e)
    }
}
```

It didn't help.

What am I doing wrong? And what's the right way to implement synchronization for my case? That is, two thread calling the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading issues are never about threads calling the same classes. It is about sharing mutable state between threads.
As I can see, your shared state are the matrices.

What are you doing wrong is hard to say without reviewing your whole code. But here are a few hints:
/ viewPole.calcMatrix() returns a reference to mat4_B.
In display() this reference is then used outside the synchronized block. So mat4_B could potentially be modified concurrently while in use by display()
/ viewPole.calcMatrix() and objectPole.calcMatrix() are called in separate synchronized blocks. So the viewPole matrix might be based on a different state then the objectPole matrix. I can not tell if this is an issue for your use case.

The approach should be to:
/ reduce shared state as much as possible (i.e. by passing copies)
/ fetching all data in a single, atomic (synchronized) operation